# How to pass arrays as function parameter in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to pass two arrays, one is a set of dates converted to days from mySQL in PHP, the other would be simply the index numbers for the first array, so that now I have two arrays with values I would like to use for simple linear regression ( the linear regression code I got from https://richardathome.wordpress.com/2006/01/25/a-php-linear-regression-function/ The function linear regression requires two arrays to be passed into it, but I cannot figure out how to pass my two arrays to it. Following is my code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT TO_DAYS(date) FROM ordering WHERE id=1",$conn);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
// mysql_query($result,$conn) or die(mysql_error();

//echo $num_rows;


$data = array();
$days=array();
$xaAxis=array();

while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) !== false){
  $data[] = $row; // add the row in to the results (data) array
}

print_r($data); // print result


//This part is not working

for ($x = $num_rows - 1; $x > 0; $x--) {
    $days[$x] = $data[$x]['TO_DAYS(date)'] -$data[$x-1]['TO_DAYS(date)'];
    $xAxis[$x]=$x;
}
print_r($days);
print_r($xAxis);

// I need to pass my two arrays $days and $xAxis to the functions call below i.e linear regression, how?

var_dump( linear_regression(array(1, 2, 3, 4), array(1.5, 1.6, 2.1, 3.0)) );

/**
 * linear regression function
 * @param $x array x-coords
 * @param $y array y-coords
 * @returns array() m=>slope, b=>intercept
 */
function linear_regression($x, $y) {

  // calculate number points
  $n = count($x);

  // ensure both arrays of points are the same size
  if ($n != count($y)) {

    trigger_error("linear_regression(): Number of elements in coordinate arrays do not match.", E_USER_ERROR);

  }

  // calculate sums
  $x_sum = array_sum($x);
  $y_sum = array_sum($y);

  $xx_sum = 0;
  $xy_sum = 0;

  for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {

    $xy_sum+=($x[$i]*$y[$i]);
    $xx_sum+=($x[$i]*$x[$i]);

  }

  // calculate slope
  $m = (($n * $xy_sum) - ($x_sum * $y_sum)) / (($n * $xx_sum) - ($x_sum * $x_sum));

  // calculate intercept
  $b = ($y_sum - ($m * $x_sum)) / $n;

  // return result
  return array("m"=>$m, "b"=>$b);

}



mysql_close($conn);
```

I am not very clear of array functionality in PHP although @thecodeparadox was kind enough to try and help and explain on a previous occasion. Please help. Hamood

Comment: It appears that you are successfully passing 2 arrays to the function.

Comment: Does `linear_regression($days, $xAxis);` not work?

Comment: the two arrays being passed are hard coded values and not variable arrays.  @steve that get me the values stored at key TO_DAYS(date) & not the index. Steve the code prior to the linear regression function seems to be working as intended, its only that I cannot seem to figure out how to properly pass the vlaues of $days and xAxis array to the linear regression function.

Comment: @GáborBakos, I have tried passing it that way, but does not work, I just end up with a blank white screen. As to your second point the days arrays holds the difference in days between the preceding two delivery dates, what I am trying to achieve is predictability as to what the future order date would be.

Comment: @Hamood Can you give us the output of the prints? Also, to make the naming easier for you, you can use the following mysql query `SELECT TO_DAYS(date) as days FROM ordering WHERE id=1"` mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_array, and instead of `$data[] = $row;`, do `$data[] = $row['days'];`.

Comment: @HorseSMith I am sorry for the delayed response, I will get this done tomorrow, when I get back home, am away.

Comment: @HorseSMith, sorry for the late reply, I just decided to do away with passing the arrays and just incorporated the function code, into the main code, probably not the best way of doing things, but was really pressed on time, Thanks for your help in anycase